# Отправить сообщение в Whatsapp

Tags: php, api, whatsapp

Есть ли API, чтобы с помощью PHP отправить сообщение в WhatsApp?

Comment: https://github.com/chatapi/whatsApp-php https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API

Comment: а не нужно здесь покупать доступ? https://chat-api.com/ru/

Comment: насколько я знаю то whatsapp открыл апи только для бизнеса. и вам придется платить в любом случае. но я не знаю точно, никогда с ватсапом не работал

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, API у них только платное, и Вы всегда можете это легко проверить на их официальном сайте. Вот ссылка на их [API](https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api), можете ознакомиться.